# Color specific words in a string

Tags: php, css, wordpress

I am using WordPress. First I created an HTML template and created a class for specific words in strings. That works fine.

Now I was wondering if that is possible to do after I get that string from the database.

```
<h1 class="heading">Happy<span class="red-color">New Year</span> 2022 !</h1>
```

When I pull the string from the database, I get Happy "New Year" 2022 !

```
$message = the_field('message'); 

echo $message // Outputs Happy "New year" 2022 !
```

Not sure how can I color New year and other words that come in "".

I was googling but no luck.

Comment: There is no magic available. You will just have to write some code to do that. A little function sounds like a good idea like `$newBigString = colourMe($bigString, $findText, $color);` that wrapps a span around the `$findText` and returns the new amended string

Comment: Do you control the SQL being executed? If so `replace` might be useable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple function to do this using `strpos()` to find the location of the double quotes

```
$message = 'Happy "New year" 2022 !';

function colourMe($in, $color, $delim = '"')
{
    $new = $in;  // init local

    if ( ($pos = strpos( $in, $delim)) === false ) {
        // nothing to do
        return $new;
    }

    // init position holders
    $first  = null;
    $second = null;
    $first  = strpos($new, $delim);                // find first delimiter
    $second = strpos($new, $delim, $first+1);      // find second delimiter

    if ( $first && $second) ) {
        // if we have 2 delimiters
        $new = sprintf("%s <span class='$color'>%s</span>%s",
                            substr($new, 0, $first-1),
                            substr($new, $first+1, $second-$first-1),
                            substr($new, $second+1)
                );
    }
    return $new;
}

echo colourMe($message, 'red-color');
```

RESULT

```
Happy <span class='red-color'>New year</span> 2022 !
```

Now if you want it to do multiple occurances to a quoted string, then we can convert this into a recursive function which will keep calling itself until it runs ount of quoted string sets.

```
$message = 'Happy "New year" 2022! Wishing you a "Prosperous" and "Safe" year.';

function colourMe($in, $color, $delim = '"')
{
    $new = $in;  // init local
/*
    if ( ($pos = strpos( $in, $delim)) === false ) {
        // nothing to do
        return $new;
    }
*/
    // init position holders
    $first  = null;
    $second = null;
    $first  = strpos($new, $delim);                // find first delimiter
    $second = strpos($new, $delim, $first+1);      // find second delimiter

    if ( $first && $second ) {
        // if we have 2 delimiters
        $new = sprintf("%s <span class='$color'>%s</span>%s",
                            substr($new, 0, $first-1),
                            substr($new, $first+1, $second-$first-1),
                            substr($new, $second+1)
                );
    } else {
        // Must be complete
        return $new;
    }
    // Recurse to see if there is another quoted set to change
    return colourMe($new, $color, $delim);
}

echo colourMe($message, 'red-color');
```

RESULT

```
Happy <span class='red-color'>New year</span> 2022! Wishing you a <span class='red-color'>Prosperous</span> and <span class='red-color'>Safe</span> year.
```

Comment: I missed your `and other words that come in ""` sentence in the question. So had another try

Comment: thank you It works well only for first word in quote. String can have several words in quotes. For ex Happy "New Year" 2022 adn we wish "a lot of happines" joy, "play" etc.

Comment: Ok, so all we need to do is convert it into a recursive function